VirtualBox to Docker on WSL2 with SSH
I am struggling trying to establish a SSH connection from my VirtualBox VM to a Docker Container which runs on WSL2.
The SSH runs with the following port and IP-addresses:

WSL2 Port 22, IP 192.168.41.184
Virtual Box VM Port 22, IP: 192.168.56.140
Docker Container 1 on WSL2: Port 22:22 (Mapping), IP 192.168.1.2
Docker Container 2 on WSL2: Port 23:22 (Mapping), IP 192.168.1.3
Docker Container 3 on WSL2: Port 24:22 (Mapping), IP 192.168.1.4

The SSH works for the following:

Windows 10 Host to Docker Container 2 ssh -L 6000:192.168.41.184:22 root@localhost -p 23
Windows 10 Host to VM ssh root@192.168.56.140 -p 22
WSL2 to Docker Container 2 with ssh root@localhost -p 23
WSL2 to VM with ssh root@192.168.56.140 -p 22
VM to Docker Container 2 with ssh -L 6000:192.168.41.184:22 root@localhost -p 23
Container 2 to VM with ssh root@192.168.56.140 -p 22

What I would like to achieve is to SSH from the VM to the Docker Container with ssh root@192.168.1.3
I have tried it with these nfttables ip nat rules on the Virtual Box VM:
table ip nat {
        chain PREROUTING {
                type nat hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
                ip saddr 192.168.56.140 ip daddr 192.168.1.3 tcp dport 22 dnat to 192.168.41.184:22
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip saddr 192.168.56.140 ip daddr 192.168.1.3 tcp dport 22 masquerade
        }
}

and additionally those nftables rules on WSL2:
table ip nat {
        chain DOCKER {
                iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        }

        chain POSTROUTING {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                oifname != "docker0" ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
                ip saddr 192.168.1.3 ip daddr 127.0.0.1 tcp dport 24 masquerade
        }

        chain PREROUTING {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
                fib daddr type local counter packets 17 bytes 1376 jump DOCKER
                ip saddr 192.168.1.3 ip daddr 192.168.41.184 tcp dport 22 dnat to 127.0.0.1:24
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
                ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        }
}

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be correct because I get this error:
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.3 port 22: Connection refused
This is my Network diagram:


Why don’t put WSL on the same subnet as VirtualBox?

@Ramhound To be frank, that suggestion hardly makes any sense.

@TomYan - I disagree. The user has a routing issue, putting everything on the same VLAN, makes it easier to solve that problem

@Ramhound Theoretically you can of course bridge the host-only interface and the WSL interface (which is "special" and "hidden" btw) on the Windows host -- but this is Windows (and WSL) we are talking about here. Good luck not getting into a mess in doing that, if that's even possible at all. (But really, at least I myself would not just bridge networks together because "it would make things easier" anyway. That's simply not how one do networking.)

hook prerouting is the wrong hook to use for traffics originate from the host (i.e. the VM) itself. Use a chain with hook output instead. You probably should then remove ip saddr 192.168.56.140 in the dnat and masquerade rules. The masquerade rule should match with the real/new destination (192.168.41.184:22) instead.
table ip nat {
        chain output {
                type nat hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                ip daddr 192.168.1.3 tcp dport 22 dnat to 192.168.41.184:22
        }

        chain postrouting {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                ip daddr 192.168.41.184 tcp dport 22 masquerade
        }
}

The masquerade rule is actually unnecessary if 192.168.1.3 and 192.168.41.184 are covered by the same route (or different routes with the same interface) on the host. (Just FYI. That is not the case in your setup.)
The reason you should not have ip saddr 192.168.56.140 in your rules is, before the masquerade is applied, the traffics would have the source address of 10.0.2.15, because/assuming 192.168.1.3 is covered by the default route configured with the NAT network interface. Therefore, if you for whatever/no reason insist on having an ip saddr match in the rules, it would need to be ip saddr 10.0.2.15.

P.S. I have to admit that I don't understand why you are dnat'ing to 192.168.41.184:22 and stated that:

Container 2 to VM with ssh root@192.168.41.184 -p 22

(And do you really mean VM to Container 2? Or did I miss some quirky reverse tunnel whatsoever setup?)
Isn't Container 2's SSH server exposed at 192.168.41.184:23?

Docker Container 2 on WSL2: Port 23:22 (Mapping)


I'm also not sure what's the nat table in WSL is for. Do you even need it at all for anything under The SSH works for the following? Are you not exposing the SSH servers with -p in docker run or what?

Thank you. With your suggested rules I land on my WSL2.
However, I would like to SSH directly into the Container 2 from my VM. Do you have an idea how to achieve this?
P.S. I had an error in my question regarding the connection from Container 2 To VM. I have corrected it in my original question

@Kai78 By land on my WSL, do you mean there is a "non-container" SSH server running in WSL, listening on port 22? (Then why did you state that port 22 of Container 1 is mapped with port 22 of WSL? While iptables / nftables themselves allows that, doesn't docker reject such request?) As I mentioned in my answer, if your Container 2's port 22 is mapped with port 23 on the WSL, obviously you should dnat to 192.168.41.184:23 instead (and match with dport 23 instead in the masquerade rule).

Yes there is also an SSH Server running on WSL2 which runs on port 22. The SSH on the two Docker Container run on port 23 and 24.
Thanks to your input I created this rule on my WSL2:
nft add rule ip nat OUTPUT ip daddr 192.168.41.184 tcp dport 24 dnat to 127.0.0.1:24
and on my VM I added those two rules:
nft add rule ip nat OUTPUT ip daddr 192.168.1.3 tcp dport 22 dnat to 192.168.41.184:24
nft add rule ip nat POSTROUTING ip daddr 192.168.41.184 tcp dport 24 masquerade
Do you want to edit your answer so I can mark it as resolution?

@Kai78 I'm pretty sure you don't need to add the/any rule yourself on WSL for the VM to be able to reach the containers. Even if you do, it won't be the rule in your comment. (Are you trying to made using 192.168.41.184:24 to address the container possible when ssh from within WSL itself with that rule?)

Yes exactly. I've put the port behind the WSL2 IP address on the Rule on my VM so that I can make a rule in WSL2 to catch it and forward it to localhost:24. With this configuration I am able to SSH from my VM to my Container directly

@Kai78 the output hook doesn't catch traffics from outside the the WSL. And when you expose/map/publish a docker container's port, the docker engine will add the necessary dnat rule for you (depending on which iptables variant you use, you might or might not see the rule it adds in nft list ruleset; check iptables-save instead). The correct dnat (added by docker) would be the other way round: ip daddr 192.168.41.184 tcp dport 24 dnat to 192.168.1.3:22.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
